# Chrome - Google account settings - Same domain - Cannot get cookies

Tags: google-chrome, web, cookies

I am developping 2 web sites

- Site 1 url = samesubdomain.samedomain.xy/subfolder**X**/index.php
- Site 2 url = samesubdomain.samedomain.xy/subfolder**Y**/index.php

Some cookies are sent by site 1: All these cookies are

- HTTPonly = yes,
- Same site = Lax,
- Secure=Yes,
- domain =  samesubdomain.samedomain.xy

When I browse Site 2 from a link in Site 1 in various browsers:

- Cookies from Site 1 are available in site 2. It works **SO FAR SO GOOD !**
- **But** they are **not passed from site 1 to site 2 when my browser is connected to a specific google account**.
- When I disconnect from this google account it works.
- When browser is connected to one of my 3 other google accounts it also works.

Cleaning browsing history (cookies, visited sites, files, etc) doesn't change anything.

Up to now I couldn't find the reason of this different behavior. All of these google accounts are set to accept "All cookies". Any idea about what could happen ?